# Compilation Error: Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors

I am getting the error:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately

On the following code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LbInsert" ValidationGroup="INSERT" OnClick="LbInsert_Click" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
```

I am unable to find out the reason

Answer (score 0):

Open the solution in Visual Studio and try to build it. If it has compile errors fix them. Also Check the .net version you are running is correct for the project and you are using the correct app pool?

Comment: Build is succeeded. It doesn't show any compilation error. but it is showing error when I am running it on browser

Comment: Both IIS and your application are running under SAME .NET Version?